# How to change of page with controller in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm doing buy app and i need check if the cart is empty or not, if is not empty I need to be redirected to another page. I can use ng-click it? Or have another way?

```
$scope.checkCart = function(){
    if($scope.items.length != 0){
           //how can I do this?
    }
    else{
        $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: "Você não fez nenhum pedido ainda!",
            okText: "Confirmar",
            okType: "button-dark"
        });
```

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.controller('your controller', function($scope, $state,...){
     $scope.checkCart = function(){
     if($scope.items.length != 0){
       $state.go(//the page what you want);
     }
     else{
        $ionicPopup.alert({
           title: "Você não fez nenhum pedido ainda!",
           okText: "Confirmar",
           okType: "button-dark"
        });
    }
```

})